# Why does this work on this, but not on this? [Selenium] [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm making a stock checker and I have a bit of a problem when I go to Amazon (AMZN) in [finance.yahoo.com](http://finance.yahoo.com). My code works perfectly, but when I try for example Tesla (TSLA) it doesn't work. Here is part of my code.

```
getperstock = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"]').text #Works
print(str(getperstock))
#"Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($negativeColor)"
getstockratio = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($positiveColor)"]').text #Doesnt
print(str(getstockratio))
```

Comment: Can you include a copy of the html element in question.

Comment: `<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($positiveColor)" data-reactid="51">+0.66 (+1.03%)</span>`

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Message Above

Comment: What error does it display?

Comment: It seems to work on this page https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA?p=TSLA&.tsrc=fin-srch but I would suggest using webdriver waits due to page load.

Comment: I'll try waiting!

Comment: It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: "I have a bit of a problem when I go to Amazon (AMZN) in finance.yahoo.com. My code works perfectly, but when I try for example Tesla (TSLA) it doesn't work. Here is part of my code." Hold on. If it works perfectly when you look up AMZN, and it doesn't work when you look up TSLA... why do you say you "have a bit of a problem when [you] go to AMZN"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the minimal HTML

```html
<div class="D(ib) Mend(20px)" data-reactid="31">
    <span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"
        data-reactid="32">670.97</span>
    <span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($negativeColor)"
        data-reactid="33">-20.65 (-2.99%)</span>
    <div id="quote-market-notice" class="C($tertiaryColor) D(b) Fz(12px) Fw(n) Mstart(0)--mobpsm Mt(6px)--mobpsm"
        data-reactid="34">
        <span data-reactid="35">At close: 4:00PM EDT</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your first xpath to get the first `span` is OK. But the second `span` will include `negative` or `positive` so if the stock is going negatively/positively, it will fail to locate the element. I see that in your comment you said it worked, but I'm sure that once it goes the opposite way, it will fail.

Better way to do it:

```py
# get parent of both `span`
parent = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="D(ib) Mend(20px)"]')
# get the `span` insides
span_elems = parent.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")

# first one is the stock price
price = span_elems[0].text
# second span is the %
ratio = span_elems[1].text
# third one is the "at close..." but you dont need it
```

By the way, don't use `find_elements...` to find the parent node. Use explicit wait will make the code do the waiting part efficiently for you: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html